# sql server 2008 r2 compare int with double

Tags: sql-server, casting, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table with double values, i want to get data form table.

I want to send int to the stored procedure and compare it to that double, but I want to compare if the int of that double for example

I have `33.3654` and if I send `33` the result should be true.

I tried this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getRestaurantNear
    (
    @lat INT,
    @lon INT,
    @ID INT OUTPUT,
    @restaurantID INT OUTPUT,
    @description VARCHAR(200) OUTPUT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT ID, restaurantID, description
    FROM RestaurantAddressMap
    WHERE CAST(lat AS INTEGER) = @lat
    AND
    CAST(lon AS INTEGER) = @lon
END
```

but the results is empty

Comment: use FLOOR
FLOOR(33.3654) = 33

Comment: SQL Server 2008 has geography types and would let you do a much better job of assessing nearness by letting you compute distances between points on the earth. Why are you not using those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getRestaurantNear
(
      @lat INT
    , @lon INT
)
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
          ID
        , restaurantID
        , [description]
    FROM dbo.RestaurantAddressMap
    WHERE ROUND(lat, 0) = @lat
        AND ROUND(lon, 0) = @lon

END
```

Comment: The OP has only given one example of the conversion. For all we know, they want `ROUND` not `FLOOR`.